# Keep linux child window on top of parent window with Qt

Tags: linux, qt

I am using qt to write a linux (here: Ubuntu) application.
I set the main window stay on top and fullscreen, and then make the other children windows. The problem is that these window go behind the main window  as soon as the main window is clicked.
Is there any way to avoid this and keep the child windows on top of main window?
Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem with a very simple setup, but I failed, since what I wrote seems to have exactly the behavior that you described as desired: window is opened in full screen, then in my example there is a single push button in the main window and upon clicking it, a child window is spawned, but for me this window stays on top of the parent all the time, even if give focus to the parent. 
Can you check if this also has the desired behavior for you?

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, public Ui::MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include <QDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  QDialog *dialog = new QDialog(this);
  dialog->show();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.showFullScreen();

    return a.exec();
}
```